# Why won't the fillRect command show up on my JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

so I'm trying to draw a rectangle when the mouse is clicked by creating an object an adding it to the JFrame. But it won't show up once the command is run. Any ideas why?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Gui3 extends JFrame {
    private JPanel mousepanel;
    private JLabel statusbar;

    public Gui3(){
        super("The title");

        mousepanel = new JPanel();
        mousepanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        add(mousepanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        statusbar = new JLabel("Default");
        add(statusbar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();
        mousepanel.addMouseListener(handler);
        mousepanel.addMouseMotionListener(handler);
    }   
    private class HandlerClass implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener
        {
```

This is where the problem is arising. The program and all its methods work, it's just drawing the rectangle that is the problem. The Object that draws the shape is below.

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
        statusbar.setText(String.format("Clicked at %d,%d",event.getX(),event.getY()));
                DrawShapes shapes = new DrawShapes();
                add(shapes);
            }
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event){
                statusbar.setText("You pressed down the mouse");
            }
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event){
                statusbar.setText("You released the button");
            }
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event){
                statusbar.setText("You entered the area");
                mousepanel.setBackground(Color.RED);
            }
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event){
                statusbar.setText("The mouse has left the window");
                mousepanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            }
            //These are mouse motion events
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event){
                statusbar.setText("You are dragging the mouse");
            }
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event){
                statusbar.setText("You are moving the mouse");
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the object that draws the rectangle

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class DrawShapes extends JPanel {
    public void PaintComponent(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(0,0,30,30);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

regarding

```
public void PaintComponent(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillRect(0,0,30,30);
}
```

Understand that

```
PaintComponent != paintComponent
```

Be sure to use the `@Override` annotation to let you know when you are or aren't overriding methods that you think you are.

The correct method would look something like:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);  // don't forget this!
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 30, 30);
}
```

Also, if you want to replace the original JPanel, then use a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) to help you easily do this. Otherwise you must be sure to call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` yourself after swapping components in a container.

e.g.,

```
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
        statusbar.setText(String.format("Clicked at %d,%d", event.getX(), event.getY()));
        remove(mousepanel);
        DrawShapes shapes = new DrawShapes();
        getContentPane().add(shapes, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        getContentPane().revalidate();
        getContentPane().repaint();
    }
```

Comment: (1+) Also you should be overriding the `getPreferredSize()` method of your class to that this component can by used by other layout managers. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step3.html) for a working example that shows exactly how this is done. Keep a link to the tutorial handy since it has information on all of the Swing basics.

Comment: @camickr: thanks. Sorry to go off topic, but any thoughts on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35989725/why-settext-method-is-not-working-on-jtextfield)? Don't you agree that it needs an [mcve]?

Comment: I think every question should have an MCVE. Whenever I see a question with 20+ comments I avoid the question because the OP just doesn't take the time to listen to the advice given. We both know 1) a DocumentFilter should be used not a custom Document and 2) the problem is with the code that is not posted.